# User credentials are null when using getSession() in middleware, next-auth

Tags: redux, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to access the user credentials from the JWT & Session using callbacks

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import User from "../../../models/user";
import dbConnect from "../../../config/dbConnect";

export default NextAuth({

    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },

    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {

                dbConnect()

                const { email, password } = credentials;

                //check if email and password is entered

                if(!email || !password) {

                    throw new Error('Please enter email or password');
                }

                //Find user in the database
                const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password')

                if(!user) {

                    throw new Error('Invalid email or password')
                }

                //Check if password is correct or not
                const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);

                if(!isPasswordMatched) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid email or password')
                }
                return Promise.resolve(user)
            }
        })
    ],

    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
            if (user) {
              token.accessToken = user.access_token
            }
            return token
        },

        session: async (session, user) => {

            session.user = user.user
            return Promise.resolve(session)
        }        
    }
})
```

then I try accessing the details in the callback using getSession() method

```
import catchAsyncErrors from './catchAsyncErrors'
import ErrorHandler from '../utils/errorHandler'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const isAuthenticatedUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {

    let session = await getSession({ req });

    console.log(session)

    if (!session) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Login first to access this resource', 401));
    }

    req.user = session.user;
    next();

})

export {
    isAuthenticatedUser
}
```

I then use the use()and handler methods from next connect to pass in the middleware

```
import nc from 'next-connect';
import dbConnect from '../../config/dbConnect';
import { currentUserProfile } from '../../controllers/authControllers'
import onError from '../../middlewares/errors';
import { isAuthenticatedUser } from '../../middlewares/auth'

const handler = nc({onError});

dbConnect();

handler.use(isAuthenticatedUser).get(currentUserProfile);


export default handler;
```

However, this is the error I get after trying to access the user credentials using the /api/me route: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')"

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
  session: async (session, user) => {

        session.user = user.user
        return Promise.resolve(session)
    }
```

From the docs:

> When using database sessions, the User object is passed as an
> argument. When using JSON Web Tokens for sessions, the JWT payload is
> provided instead.

so you are passing wrong arg. you have to destructure it:

```
   session: async ({session, user}) => {
        session.user = user.user
        return Promise.resolve(session)
    }
```

this is example from the docs. pay attention to the arg

```
callbacks: {
  async session({ session, token, user }) {
    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken
    return session
  }
}
```